# anime.js to vidéo

Tags: javascript, browser, css-animations, mp4, anime.js

Yes this is my first post here!!!

I'm looking for the way to export MP4 files from my Firefox browser.

I work on anime.js and my clients ask me for MP4 videos.

Thanks in advance!

I try to find some files in P5.js, but did not find...

Comment: Besides recording the screen you can try the following [Anime.js to MP4 and GIF with Node.js and FFMPEG](https://soshace.com/anime-js-to-mp4-and-gif-with-node-js-and-ffmpeg/).

Comment: You need an **MP4 encoder**. MP4 expects to contain video frames that are **compressed to the H264 standard** (_eg:_ instead of the JPEG standard or some other image compression). You need those pieces together... Try looking for `Javascript H264 encoder` or `Javascript MP4 encoder`. You can try: https://github.com/TrevorSundberg/h264-mp4-encoder (click the GREEN `Code` button to see a download option for the ZIP file).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the simplest solution will be to put your browser into fullscreen mode and record your screen.

There are more elaborate solutions, but honestly nothing that has steep benefits over just simply recording your own browser on your own screen. If your monitor's resolution is good enough, if your animation reliably plays back at full speed on your machine, there's no benefit at all to doing more than just going fullscreen and hitting your OS's record button.